# Can't use action bar in androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-actionbar

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        toolbaTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbaTitleTextView);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                mToolbar, R.string.application_name,
                R.string.application_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                toolbaTitleTextView.setText(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

nice. it's work fine.

but in old project I use

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
```

is it possible use `ActionBarDrawerToggle` with `actionbar` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this `ActionBarDrawerToggle` will also work `ActionBar`.

Here [ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle) is also present in `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`

I also checked- `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor also works with `ActionBar`.

```
        ActionBar actionBar;
        ...
        ..
        toolbaTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbaTitleTextView);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                actionBar, R.string.application_name,
                R.string.application_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                toolbaTitleTextView.setText(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I need use androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle. I can not   use android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle

Comment: Then, No! It is not possible. You can either use the old support library or AndroidX.

Comment: Why don't you migrate your old project to AndroidX ?

Comment: I use very old project. And migrate take long time

Comment: I have done in my old projects. It doesn't take long. I would advice to do so. You can migrate to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar. It's that simple. You can follow this [MIgrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)